# Word keeps resetting heading number to 1

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, title

I'm having a problem with word where it keeps resetting to heading number 1 like half way through the document where I want to continue the numbers. I have tried the option to continue numbering but that doesnt work. Any help?

MS Word 2007

Answer (score 1):

Are you entering a blank line between the numbered sections? for instance:

1) numbered sentence one

2) numbered sentence two

3) numbered sentence three

A sentence on a separate line goes here.

1) A new line numbered sentence one

2) New line numbered sentence two

If so, then that is Words normal operation. It can be fixed for selected text areas by going to:
Format/Bullets and numbering/ and then selecting "continue from"...

but nothing that I know of will cause it to just automatically keep counting up.